# Объявление значений в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть код, реализующий расстояния между всеми точками. Я хочу использовать для этого цикл считывания элементов, количества и значений массива со строк, но прежде, запустить код программы в Visual Studio 2010. В онлайн-компилляторах на код не ругается, а в VS на объявление массивов с конкретными элементами - ругается.

Почему так?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include "math.h"
    using namespace std;

    void alldist(int *x, int *y, int n) 
    {
        float d;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                d = sqrt(pow((x[j] - x[i]), 2) + pow((y[j] - y[i]), 2));
                cout <<"dist "<< i << ":" << j << " " << d << " ";
            }
                cout << endl;
        }
    }
    int main() {
        int *x=new int [5] {1, 4, 6, 2, 1}; 
        int *y=new int [5] {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; 
        alldist(x, y, 5);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) initializer lists доступен только с c++11, vs2010 его не поддерживает

```
new int [5] {1, 4, 6, 2, 1}
            ^
```

2) зачем тебе new для этого массива когда можно просто написать?

```
int x[] = {1, 4, 6, 2, 1};
```

Comment: А как тогда задать этот массив?

Comment: добавил пример в ответ